# How to guarantee unique primary key with one update query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my Movie schema, I have a field "release_date" who can contain nested subdocuments.

These subdocuments contains three fields :

- country_code
- date
- details

I need to guarantee the first two fields are unique (primary key).

I first tried to set a unique index. But I finally realized that MongoDB does not support unique indexes on subdocuments.
Index is created, but validation does not trigger, and I can still add duplicates.

Then, I tried to modify my update function to prevent duplicates, as explained in this article (see Workarounds) : http://joegornick.com/2012/10/25/mongodb-unique-indexes-on-single-embedded-documents/

$ne works well but in my case, I have a combination of two fields, and it's a way more complicated...

$addToSet is nice, but not exactly what I am searching for, because "details" field can be not unique.

I also tried plugin like mongoose-unique-validator, but it does not work with subdocuments ...

I finally ended up with two queries. One for searching existing subdocument, another to add a subdocument if the previous query returns no document.

```
insertReleaseDate: async(root, args) => {
  const { movieId, fields } = args

  // Searching for an existing primary key
  const document = await Movie.find(
    {
      _id: movieId,
      release_date: {
        $elemMatch: {
          country_code: fields.country_code,
          date: fields.date
        }
      }
    }
  )

  if (document.length > 0) {
    throw new Error('Duplicate error')
  }

  // Updating the document
  const response = await Movie.updateOne(
    { _id: movieId },
    { $push: { release_date: fields } }
  )

  return response
}
```

This code works fine, but I would have preferred to use only one query.

Any idea ? I don't understand why it's so complicated as it should be a common usage.

Comment: why not putting your query which tries to find documents into your update query? so {_id : movieId, $not : {releaseDate ...}}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks RichieK for your answer ! It's working great.

Just take care to put the field name before "$not" like this :

```
insertReleaseDate: async(root, args) => {
  const { movieId, fields } = args

  const response = await Movie.updateOne(
    {
      _id: movieId,
      release_date: {
        $not: {
          $elemMatch: {
            country_code: fields.country_code,
            date: fields.date
          }
        }
      }
    },
    { $push: { release_date: fields } }
  )

  return formatResponse(response, movieId)
}
```

Thanks a lot !